# Sense HAT stuck on Rainbow test, will not show any blue light in normal RGB

Tags: sense-hat, pi-400

I am new to this, and my Sense HAT is stuck on a rainbow setting and only shows Red and green, instead of Red, Green, and Blue. I have a Raspberry Pi 400, an Acer monitor, and I am using a 40 pin ribbon cable (F2F) to connect the Raspberry Pi 400 and the Sense Hat. I get the following error when I tried to write code in Thonny Python IDE. I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/Desktop/PY Sense Hat/Rainbow.py", line 2, in <module>
sense = SenseHat()

File "usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sense_hat/sense_hat.py", line 39, in init
raise OSError ('Cannot detect %s device' % self.SENSE_HAT_FB_NAME)
OSError: Cannot detect RPi-Sense FB device
```

I have researched and found leads on this topic, BUT none of them seem to work. I have already tried the
`sudo config` already but it isnt helping me. I have come to the conclusion that I either have a faulty Sense HAT; I have tried 2 Sense HATs and I get the same rainbow issue, or it is that I have a bad SD card; I haven't found anything wrong with it. Can someone please explain what is wrong? My Raspberry Pi 400 works fine, as well as my monitor. my Sense HAT is the only thing that doesn't work. When I tilt it on the ribbon cable, it will show the full rainbow complete with the rg**b**, but still will not function normally. I do not know what Operating System I am using, but I think it is Raspian OS. The moment that I apply power, the Sense Hat turns on and then stays on a rainbow pattern. My Sense Hat also starts to heat up. Is this normal??

[image: Sense Hat]
[image: Raspberry Pi 400]

Comment: You need to EDIT your question and include details.  What is working?  What is not working?  What operating system are you using?  What happens when you apply power?

Comment: What if you apply power without an SD card? Can you change the color of any pixel?

Comment: I can't change the color of any pixel at all, the Raspberry Pi 400 doesn't work without a SD card, and now when i plug it in, the colors only appear when my raspberry Pi 400 is off.

Comment: You should detach the hat and [test the GPIOs as described here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/132853/5538).  There are some concerning things in your post: *"When I tilt it on the ribbon cable, it will show the full rainbow complete"* -> That physically moving it while attached to a ribbon cable causes a change in state implies a loose connection, a broken connector, or worse (although an unlikely scenario is it has to do with the gyroscope).

Comment: *"My Sense Hat also starts to heat up."* -> You should go into more detail about this, as (while I don't have a sense hat), I very much doubt that is normal.  How hot? Is it uncomfortable to touch? **Do both the hats do this** (you mention having two to test with that both do the same thing)?  What parts specifically are hot?  I do not know how accessible the Pi is inside that keyboard but you might want to get to it if possible and check if there are unusually hot components there.

Answer (score 0):

It's simply the wrong way around on the ribbon cable!

The cable has to plug into the TOP of the sense hat, instead of the bottom. Pin 1 on the Pi must go to Pin 1 on the Hat. I wish they had marked pin 1 on the hat. Pin 1 on the hat is right next to the label "J1" on the left side, inner row.